# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element. Can some one help me?

Tags: python, selenium, exception, xpath, webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./drivers/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')

name = input('Enter the name of user or group: ')
msg = input('Enter your message: ')
count = int(input('How many message you want to send: '))

input('Enter anything after scanning QR code')
user = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@title = "{}"]'.format(name))
time.sleep(10)
user.click()
```

It keep giving me this message when I run it:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element.

Can some one help me? I've look it up in Stackoverflow and it told me to sleep the driver but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

When they say to "sleep the driver" they probably mean to wait *before* trying to locate an element, but it is generally a bad practice to hardcode any static amount of time to idly wait during testing. The common solution is using [expected conditions](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) which will only pause for as long as is required, with timeout:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10) 
user = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH, '//span[@title = "{}"]'.format(name))))
user.click()
```

Having said that, pay close attention to correctness of xpath expression generated by your code, and gotchas like untrimmed whitespace being part of element title in the DOM, incorrect tag, locator matching multiple elements, one of which is not currently visible and clickable.